# Implement a UNIX file system and command line parser

Tags: code-golf, parsing

### Description

Your task is to implement a simple UNIX command parser and file system. Your program will have to implement a file system that can be modified via commands.

The starting directory of your file system is an empty root directory `/`, with no subdirectories or files. Your program must be capable of handling the following commands:

### Commands

`cd <dirpath>` - Change the current directory

- `<dirpath>` will be a list of directory names or "..", seperated by "/"
- e.g. `cd ../folder1/folder2` means to navigate up one directory level, then descend into `folder1`, then descend into `folder2`
- If the directory path is not valid, then the command will do nothing

`touch <filename>` - Create a new file

- e.g. `touch me.txt` creates a file called `me.txt` in the current directory
- Filenames will only contain characters a-z and "."

  - Filenames will contain "." at least once
  - "." will never be the first or last character in a file name
- If a file already exists with the same name in the current directory, nothing happens

`mkdir <dirname>` - Create a new directory

- e.g. `mkdir photos` creates a new `photos` directory in the current directory
- Directory names will only contan characters a-z
- If a directory already exists with the same name in the current directory, nothing happens

`rm [-r] <filename-or-dirname>` - Remove a file or directory

- e.g. `rm hello.mp3` removes a file named `hello.mp3` in the current directory
- e.g. `rm -r documents` removes a folder named `documents` in the current directory, and all of its contents
- If `rm` tries to delete a directory without the `-r` flag, nothing will happen

  - However `rm` will delete a file even with the `-r` flag
- If the specified directory or file cannot be found, nothing happens

### Tree output

Your program will output the following tree-like representation of the current file system using spaces as indentation. For example:

```
/
  documents
    document.docx
  downloads
    zippedfile
      notavirus.exe
    coolgoats.mp3
    zippedfile.zip
  pictures
    myvacation.png
```

- <s>All directories names must end with a "/"</s> no longer necessary
- You may use any number of spaces to indent the tree (minimum 1)
- Directories must be listed before files in the same directory
- <s>Directories and files should be listed in lexographical alphabetical order</s>

  - <s>The character "." lexographically comes before any alphabetical character</s>
- You may output the contents of directories in any order you wish

### Challenge

Create a program that accepts a series of commands, and outputs a tree-like representation of the current file system.

**Input**

The first line of input will be an integer `N`. Following will be `N` lines, each containing a command as described above.

You may feel free to omit the number `N` from your input if it is not necessary

Slight variations are allowed (using commas to seperate commands, input as a list etc) as long as it's reasonable

**Output**

The contents of the current file system in a tree-like representation, as described above.

### Test Cases

Input 1: Simple example from earlier

```
15
mkdir documents
cd documents
touch document.docx
cd ..
mkdir downloads
cd downloads
touch coolgoats.mp3
touch zippedfile.zip
mkdir zippedfile
cd zippedfile
touch notavirus.exe
cd ../..
mkdir pictures
cd pictures
touch myvacation.png
```

Output 1:

```
/
  documents
    document.docx
  downloads
    zippedfile
      notavirus.exe
    coolgoats.mp3
    zippedfile.zip
  pictures
    myvacation.png
```

Input 2:
Incorrect commands and edge cases

```
12
mkdir folder1
mkdir folder1
mkdir folder2
rm folder1
rm -r folder2
cd ..
cd ../folder1
cd folder1/folder2
touch file.txt
touch file.txt
touch file2.txt
rm -r file2.txt
```

Output 2:

```
/
  folder1
  file.txt
```

Input 3:
<s>Alphabetical listing of directories and files</s> no longer necessary

```
8
mkdir b
mkdir c
mkdir a
touch c.txt
touch aa.txt
touch b.txt
touch a.txt
touch ab.txt
```

Output 3:

```
/
  a
  b
  c
  a.txt
  aa.txt
  ab.txt
  b.txt
  c.txt
```

Input 4:
Partially correct cd should not be parsed (Suggested by @Arnauld)

```
4
mkdir folder1
cd folder1
cd ../folder2
touch file.txt
```

Output 4:

```
/
  folder1
    file.txt
```

Input 5:
Partially correct cd should not be parsed (Suggested by @Abigail)

```
3
mkdir foo
cd bar/../foo
touch file.txt
```

Output 5:

```
/
  foo
  file.txt
```

Standard loopholes and I/O rules apply.

**This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest code wins.**

**Edit:** output requirements have been relaxed a little bit

Comment: I would suggest allowing for a more flexible output that would still convey the tree-like structure! Other than that, good job!

Comment: @RGS what kind of flexibility would you suggest?

Comment: "in UTF-8 bytes" — languages that use no more than 256 distinct characters, but have their own character set, are to be punished?

Comment: It seems like we only need to parse the path for the `cd` command and will never be given something like `touch ../foo/bar`. Can you confirm that?

Comment: "You may use any number of spaces to indent the tree" ― even zero?

Comment: @Arnauld yes touch and mkdir will only ever be given file or folder names, no path parsing necessary ;)

Comment: @Adám I will clarify the spaces for indenting the tree, thanks for pointing it out. Also, what is the standard rule for scoring code golf? I always thought it was just UTF-8 bytes

Comment: "Filenames will contain "." at least once". That's not very UNIX like. ""." will never be the first or last character in a file name". Neither is this.

Comment: Starting from an empty state, followed by `mkdir foo`, does `cd bar/../foo` descend into `foo`, or is this an illegal path and thus nothing happens?

Comment: @Abigail cd bar/../foo is not valid because bar doesn't exist. I will add that as a test case

Comment: Explaination for mkdir: "Directory names will only contan characters a-z"

Comment: @MrSiliconGuy Sorry, I missed that rule. Some of your test cases have digits in file names and directory names. Is this intentional?

Comment: oops, definitely not. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @MrSiliconGuy Look [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5879/43319) for our default policy on counting bytes.

Comment: @Arnauld that's unecessary, `touch` description - `Filenames will contain "." at least once` so names for dirs and files will never overlap

Comment: What happens if I try to `cd ..` while in the root directory?  Or if I try to `cd ../../../../..` while in `/foo/bar`?  Using @Abigail's example, if I'm in `/` and directories `/foo` and `/baz` exist, is `cd baz/../foo` legal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <s>133</s> 86 bytes

```bash
(for i;{
$i
[[ $PWD =~ , ]]||cd ->~/e
})
tree --dirsfirst|sed '$d;s#[^0-Z.]# #g;1c /'
```

*-2 bytes thanks to @Dom Hastings (removing spaces around `||`)*

*-6 bytes thanks to @Dom Hastings (removing `eval`  before `$i` and using `#` as a sed delimiter)*

*-12 bytes thanks to @ilkkachu (combining the `sed`s).*

*-5 bytes thanks to @chepner (`=~`, `$PWD` and sed `c` command)*

Takes input where each argument is a command, e.g. `script 'mkdir A' 'cd A' 'touch B'`

Must be called from an empty directory with name containing `,`, such that this directory is the only directory containing `,` on the system.

The code itself is 85 bytes, +1 byte for specifying the directory name.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7RTsQgEEXf@YpJ2GR101KNj41@iE3NIky7xBYI0N1Vq7@OaNmqyZDcOzPnMs/cH@L4IpWDgggJRbzqjANVv5ONIk0De3uSe7iHXbGDtp3ntFM@fFZIPq5JcIhQlgn2XXph9ihhu5G1p83TTfnIWgq0r289ZbSi2xjzT9KIaUQdfExp/wxj1aViMJM4rGOWxHlZWVNOejBc5pSLWTBhzNAbHjwb7V3uvSlrUXZqQJZkTvltfsf8cQujTeBH5SbP8IzrhZm1SoTJ4c8Bq1648fXIBQ/KaGZ1/wU).

**How it Works**

```bash
(         # start a subshell
for i;do  # for each argument
 $i          # run that command (rm [-r], touch, and mkdir 
             # behave exactly as specified)
             # unfortunately cd can leave the directory, so...
 if [[ $PWD != *,* ]];then  # if we left the directory
                              # (i.e. the directory now no longer contains a comma)
    cd - > ~/e                     # cd to the directory from before the command
                                   # if this is successful, it outputs the new directory to stdout
                                   # so, redirect stdout to a file we can edit
                                   # piping to : didn't work without more bytes
                                   # It would be nice to not have to do this, but 
                                   # redirecting the final `tree` output to a file included that file half the time 
 fi
done
) # end subshell, returning to the initial directory (corresponding to '/')
tree --dirsfirst  # tree does most of the work for us
                  # outputs nearly the desired output, but it looks like
                  # .
                  # ├── A
                  # │   └── B.txt
                  # └── F
                  # 2 directories, 1 file

 | sed '
   $d;              # remove the last line ("2 directories, 1 file")
   s#[^0-Z.]# #g;   # replace all characters that are not digits, letters, or '.' with a space
   1c /             # replace the initial '.' with a '/'
 '
```

Comment: I think you should be able to remove the spaces ariund` &&` for -2!

Comment: This is pretty clever, using built-in bash to do all the work for you

Comment: Can you somehow use `chroot` here?

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate I was just looking at this too, but i needed to alias in the commands... Might be a mechanism there (although needs root) Also, the `3` in `mp3` is stripped, so you need to add `0-9` into your `sed` arg: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7NbsMgEITvPMUeLOVHBir1VFV5kdqOQmFNUG2DADtp6z67S2LX6QFpZsQ3O@8inKf2QxkPOZEK8mlbWw/m9Zuow8ld1IngIBrIDCkKyLYp2cEB9vkeqmocE5Ep8rMj0SMCpakn1OnFUXt0QAfIx4AKAi@Ogr6xJ/pS8RK4vqebwI8l4yXnejNNywxlZd9iF8OUyh8m2l6eV8@SuN4@MLZil66xQi3Yn5kxaW2jrYiBte55yb6Mc6hq0yBLcml5hLeaf25mOhvFYHwfGF5xPs/XBc7I2Hu8D1j1zLWfg5AiGtsx1@lf "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: Also, to avoid escaping the `/` you can use another delimiter: `sed s#^\.#/#` and `\A` instead of quotes and `^`, it's also possible to just call `$i` instead of `eval` (I think anyway, this test case works) and `cd -` should take you back if you've left `,`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5BT8QgEIXv/IpJuofdTQETT8Z48G/Y1gSBssQWCNDuqvW3Iyu162GS917mezNvLJzS@C60hxpxAXXa99aDfvxCO42aBnZ7dxYHeIJjfYSuW5a8hNH3AUUvJWCcydDniYvy0gGeoV6CFBBo88rwC7nDDx1tgaqSVu1zSypaqZTWs8LyaZQmhpSbbybaiZ82T7K4XBcI2bCzGSwTK/ZnCsatHZRlMZDR3a/Zp3ZOil4PkmS5ttzCa80/VxhjI5u1nwKRF1nO0@0Dp3mcvPx9YNOFGz9mxlnU1hBn1A8)

Comment: @DomHastings Yes, just `$i` works. I had `cd -`, but the hard part was redirecting its output since it outputs the location it returns to. The `\A` would be more bytes than `^` since quotes were unnecessary anyway (and the `\` would itself have to be escaped in that case).

Comment: `tree --dirsfirst|sed '/,/d;s/[^0-Z.]/ /g;s#^\.#/#'` should work with at least GNU sed. Or even `sed '$d;s/[^0-Z.]/ /g;s#^\.#/#'` if it's just the last line you want to remove, not any lines with a `,`. (`d` is for delete, `/,/` is a regular regex condition and `$` for the last line)

Comment: You can knock off a couple more bytes; replace the call to `pwd` with the parameter `$PWD`, and use `=~` match the regular expression `,` instead of pattern-matching.

Comment: Replace `1s#.#/#` with `1c\<nl>.` to save another couple bytes (`<nl>` is a literal newline).

Comment: @chepner The `\<nl>` is [unnecessary](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) for the `c` command, saving another 2.

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <sup><s>358</s> ... <s>280</s></sup> 277 bytes

thanks to [randomdude999](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/71803/randomdude999) for -3 bytes and a bugfix.

Input is a list of commands, where each command is represented by a 2-tuple as `(cmd, args)`. Test cases can be transformed using [this Retina program](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X0NP215TAUhqcmmoqxiq6yioqxipa3Id2salo8CVEMcVzZWgwhX7/39udkpmkUJafj5XcopCUmKRvp6ePohXkl@anKGQlpmTqldSUQIA).

```python
K=T={}
for c,a in input():
 try:exec"T[a]=1|x=a<'.';if x or T[a]<2:del T[a[3*x:]]|T[a]=T.get(a,{'..':T})|E=T\nfor p in a.split('/'):E=E[p]\nT=E".split('|')[hash(c)%6]
 except:1
def p(t,i):
 for k in sorted(t,cmp,t.get,1):
	if'..'<k:print i+k;t[k]>1!=p(t[k],i+' ')
p({'/':K},'')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZNNb6MwEIbPy69wK60MW5aIVOqBhr2xlx72wo1yMMYEiw9bxrRkk/z2rE1aAoSsVishMX6YeWfmBfhO5qxenzBLCfCBgBCeXvzQ3x@NjAmAbQRorS7eStPyDCDFziMdwfdhhGLfPXQ@2kAHPtMMdEAVaLxZeykpdRg9fuu8OD70yaGzJdJE9h46DvTCo3UI/PC11m24boKchpdUmnAFLS/wg4jHr3XoB/ef/ACtKEdNbmLr61NsANJhwqXnGinJADelTfWEWq/Qeg0TkqQK44rbUje3XZXwhWZ6gE3hcUFrCehD8SyjIv7h3vlKREU2fYAAWgY392oW7@VoQ2idlDOG8Z7TkoBQtER16s1QNwC0I0Bb2J96XQN8zAeCXz8DIZg4pyaCoOIUmbAqUiqgDWDKcFuRWjbQsoEJcboAJWtxPuaOCrpxgVqpP41k3@uSoXQmO4GDLGas3DIkG6fij7NnvynnJM3U4o4KZ10uD8dt5nTQqplEb1S0jaMsm46/utqAUyxbQSYLTNmgW@3eEEaSstrh9RZasTF2OGNlSoQ7k/8bXZ@pqK4Sz@i7AJPE6TsYVppUnukHWk3Khz16l2Un/x2vL/wy2oVPjUhmy@LZGc0/i4WmCC3AZClxiSVLY922adHP26bNZdm4PkFi1Wuw/6u/LlSKlx1v/IZ9VfwH)

#### Explanation

```python
K=T={}
```

The file system is represented by a dictionary, where `K` points to the root directory, and `T` points to the current directory. Each sub-directory contains a reference to its parent directory under the key `'..'`, which allows for easy execution of `cd ..`. Files are represented by the integer `1`.

```python
for c,a in input():
 try:exec"""<touch>|<rm>|<mkdir>|<cd>""".split('|')[hash(c)%4]
 except:1
```

This loop executes the commands, the right code to execute is selected using the hash of the command (see table below). The execution is wrapped in `try/except` to catch exceptions that occur in invalid `cd` and `rm` calls.

```python
┌───────┬──────────────────────┬─────────────┐
│   cmd │            hash(cmd) │ hash(cmd)%6 │
├───────┼──────────────────────┼─────────────┤
│    cd │    12672076131114255 │           3 │
│ mkdir │ -4476162622565762260 │           2 │
│    rm │    14592087666131641 │           1 │
│ touch │  7353934562497703448 │           0 │
└───────┴──────────────────────┴─────────────┘
```

```python
# touch
T[a]=1
```

Creates a new file called `a` in the current directory.

```python
# rm
x=a<'.'
if x or T[a]<2:del T[a[3*x:]]
```

If `a` starts with `'-r'`, `x` is set to `True`. If `x` is True or we want to delete just a file (dicts are greater than integers in Python 2), the object can be deleted.

```python
# mkdir
T[a]=T.get(a,{'..':T})
```

If the current directory already has an item called `a`, do nothing. Otherwise create a new subdirectory in the current directory with name `a` with a parent reference to the current directory.

```python
# cd
E=T
for p in a.split('/'):E=E[p]
T=E
```

If p is equal to '..', `E['..']` points to the parent directory of `E`. Otherwise `E[p]` is the subdirectory `p` in `E`. The current directory is only updated if all steps have completed without error.

```python
# Function that formats and prints the file system
# t - dictionary representing a part of the file system
# i - current indentation
def p(t,i):
 # Iterate over the keys sorted ...
 # ... on the values, where dicts (directories) ...
 # ... are larger than `1` (files) ...
 # ... and reverse
 for k in sorted(t,cmp,t.get,1):
  # if k is not 0 (a parent reference) ...
  # print the name of k ...
  # and, if k is a directory, call p recursively
  if k:print i+k;t[k]>1!=p(t[k],i+' ')
```

Comment: Fails for `[('mkdir', 'foo'), ('cd', 'foo'), ('touch', 'bar'), ('cd', '..'), ('mkdir', 'foo')]`: `mkdir` should do nothing if the directory already exists, but it always recreates it.

Comment: @randomdude999 thanks for notifying me, I should've read the rules more thoroughly. This is now fixed.

Comment: Alright, now let's get golfing :) The hashes modulo 6 are exactly 3,2,1,0 for "cd","mkdir","rm","touch" respectively, so you can split touch and mkdir, saving 1 byte. You can use a single-line string for the exec and use \n or ; instead of newlines, saving 2 bytes, for a total of 277. [try it online!](https://bit.ly/2AEQfDM)

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>268 265 254</s>  248 bytes

Expects an array of strings. Returns a single linefeed-separated string.

```javascript
a=>a.map(o=r=s=>([[c],s,e]=s.split` `,c>'m'?c>r?o[s]=1:o[e||+o[s]&&s]=0:c<'m'?o=s.split`/`.every(s=>o=o[s]-2?0:o[s],q=o)?o:q:o[s]=o[s]||{'..':o}))&(g=(o,i)=>[0,1].map(t=>{for(k in o)(v=o[k],t?v^1:v-2|k<S)||(S+=i+k,t||g(v,i+' '))}))(r,`
 `,S=`/`)||S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVLLkpswELzzFZyMVMbyIzeywqfkBzh6nbIshFcxaLAkEztmv90RD2O2trJc1K3pnulR8ZtVzHAtSztTkIp7Ru@MxowUrERANTU0RpsN34YmFFtqiClzaXf@LuRxUARrHus1bMyWLiPYiLqeNmQycReLiL80ChhM8x0RldBX5HoCbYSz1XoRNSA8UcBriE4ta2t1fQsICSJ4x3iCDhRBKDGNN4twuW3TWRrfMtDo6EvlA0aVsx23oV1Xv5ZRNVvVx5cE1zVKplROj6Gt6wOqQjkN/ABj1xTpcOe5RRLqkjlhctfidJZaoCAzASZasPSnzEVyVRwtMLGQWC3VAeFuHxS8qlflhC7ED8bfkPFp7N883@egDOSC5HBAGTJPuRvsT30HZu4L8HfvHd@LYyq1nwI/F0JZ4/F0RCyc@dvAiQOXRkCI97D9UTmwtLc9SGfjAPkBmDWkKL/1d39lWYo0c2sRB/suz8umzYh1HgWWVVKfDREX0Y2fDwlKye1ZizbAgDtfca0YZ1aCIqU6eL0hgzwVevkFW3m6GAoOzp6FbvcuwkPhWA/nD1k3v93SXuz/6arl/YiB92H2/cn7kz2eddSEsRHZjwtjvB@3/Rz7wz6fwg82aHR7puetFr7WPQXO0dbHv42r/gM)

### How?

#### Part 1: parse the commands and build the tree

The file tree is described by an object whose keys are the file names and whose values are:

- **0** for a deleted entry
- **1** for a file
- another object for a directory

Each directory (except the root) contains a default `..` entry pointing to the parent directory.

```javascript
a.map(                   // main loop
  o =                    // o is the current object
  r =                    // r is the root object
  s => (                 // for each string s in a[]:
    [[c], s, e] =        //   split it into c = first character of the command,
      s.split` `,        //   s = first argument, e = second argument
    c > 'm' ?            //   if c is greater than 'm':
      c > r ?            //     if c is greater than 's':
        o[s] = 1         //       touch: create a file whose name is s
      :                  //     else:
        o[               //       rm:
          e ||           //         use e if it exists (meaning that -r was used)
          +o[s] && s     //         or use s if o[s] is a file
        ] = 0            //       mark this entry as deleted
    :                    //   else:
      c < 'm' ?          //     if c is less than 'm':
        o =              //       cd:
          s.split`/`     //         split the path
          .every(s =>    //         for each string s in the path:
            o =          //           update o:
              o[s] - 2 ? //             if o is a file or a deleted entry:
                0        //               abort
              :          //             else:
                o[s],    //               update o to o[s] (may be undefined)
            q = o        //           q = backup of o
          ) ?            //         if all entries were truthy:
            o            //           confirm the update
          :              //         else:
            q            //           restore o to q
      :                  //     else:
        o[s] = o[s] ||   //       mkdir: create a directory whose name is s,
               {'..': o} //       provided that it doesn't already exist
  )                      //
)                        // end of map()
```

#### Part 2: build the output string

```javascript
( g =                    // g is a recursive function taking:
  (o, i) =>              //   o = current object, i = indentation string
  [0, 1].map(t => {      //   for t = 0 and t = 1:
    for(k in o)          //     for each key k in o:
      (                  //
        v = o[k],        //       v = value
        t ?              //       if we are listing files:
          v ^ 1          //         abort if v is not equal to 1
        :                //       else (listing directories):
          v - 2 |        //         abort if v is a file or a deleted entry
          k < S          //         or the directory name is '..'
      ) || (             //       if the above test was falsy:
        S +=             //         append to S:
          i + k,         //           indentation + key
        t ||             //       if we are listing directories:
          g(v, i + ' ')  //         do a recursive call
      )                  //     implicit end of for()
  })                     //   end of map()
)(r, `\n `, S = `/`)     // initial call to g
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's mandatory, but your answer is missing the leading line with `/` in that output, that the test cases and other two answers have.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I think it previously did not appear in all example outputs, which is why I thought it was not mandatory. Now fixed at no cost anyway.

Comment: (@KevinCruijssen Looking at the post history, the `/` has actually always been there in all examples. I guess I just misread them.)

Comment: `mkdir foo; cd foo; touch bar.txt; cd ..; mkdir foo` (with the semicolons replaced by newlines of course) fails: `mkdir` should do nothing if the directory already exists, but in this case, it's re-created.

Comment: @randomdude999 Thank you for reporting this. Now fixed.